# How do I create communication between two holybro telematry radio to a drone?

Tags: serial-port, telemetry, dronekit-python, qgroundcontrol, mission-planner

I am currently working on a project where I want to create a python script that sends commands to my drone. I dont understand how do I create communication between the two telematry radios using python so that it will send the commands to the pixhawk. I am using pixhawk 2.4.8 and two telematry radios from holybro on 433 mhz.
I managed to create communication between the two using qgroundcontrol program but only from it. I tried using chatgpt for some scripts but they dont work as well.
some examples of scripts that i tried:

```
import asimport asyncio
from mavsdk import System

async def connect_drone():
  drone = System(mavsdk_server_address='localhost', port=14540)
  await drone.connect(system_address="serial://COM3:57600")  
return drone


async def main():
   drone = await connect_drone()
   print("Drone component info:", drone.component_information)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   asyncio.run(main())
```

this didnt work as well.
I received an error for premission denied on com3 port (by the way I use windows). and I believe the problem comes from many parts not only this one. I would love for some help to understand how to manage to send commands to my drone. thank you.